# GCP SLQ instance wont stop ,restart, or delete

Tags: google-cloud-platform

The status says "under maintenance" and has for several hours.  This is a not a large database as I am a new student with very small tables for learning.  I have tried stopping and restarting as well as deleting the instance, but get an error message every time.  The error simply says "The attempted action failed, please try again.  Request ID: 4022803414404737811".  Operations and logs shows an "update" error "unknown error" this morning, but no other information given.

I have logged out of GCP and back in with no effect.

Comment: Isn't it a rights problem. Are you a project owner? Which SQL is it?

Comment: I am the owner, so no rights problem.  its SQLpostgres.  Google tech support said "weird."  and essentially chalked it up to a glitch.  they offered the suggestion that it might have been a code problem that caused an infinite loop, but that was discredited when the new instance I was finally able to create ran just fine with the same code.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved!  I was able to get through to Google tech support and after hours of screen sharing, had the ticket escalated.  sadly the only way they could get me past it was to delete the instance.  level 1 tech support could not do this, so I had to wait for the ticket to move up.  Once the instance was deleted, I could create a new one and move on.  Sadly there was no easy fix that retained the instance, so data was lost.  Good thing it was just class exercise and not real business. (also why there wasnt a backup).
No explanation given by tech support, so nothing valuable learned here.  sorry